# How to retrieve the return code descriptions in oracle audit

Tags: oracle11g, audit-trail

I need some help in auditing in Oracle. We have a database with many tables and we want to be able to audit every change made to any table in any field. However, I find it difficult to locate the descriptions for return code. For example,

ORA-00020: maximum number of processes (number) exceeded.

So my question is which table or view holds these messages all together.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print an error message for a specified error number, you can pass the error ID to the SQLERRM function:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM(-20));
END;
/
```